# Moving div using hover

Tags: html, css

I need a small help with this code. I am trying to create a menu.
I have demonstrated this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkGR4/)

My problem is that the button(which is not really a button) keeps moving as I hover over it, what method can be used to keep it where it is?

Here is some of my code

```
    <div id="start_bar">
        <div id ="start_button">
    Test

            <div id="nav">
            Hello World
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and css

```
    #start_button{
height:48px;
width:48px;
background-image:url('images/start.png');
color:white;
}
#start_button:hover  {
height:48px;
width:48px;
background-image:url('images/start.png');
margin-top: -18px;
}

#nav {
    display: none;
}
#start_button:hover > #nav {
display: block;
width: 70px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: -150px;
background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `margin-top: -Xpx;` to move the menu into place, make it absolutely positioned `left: 0; bottom: 100%;`. This will work, and you don't have to enter a pixel height for the menu or the menu bar.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qkGR4/6/)**

In general, you want to avoid setting heights for elements. The height of an element should be dictated by the content as often as possible. Or, in this case, `position: absolute; bottom: 100%;` makes the element go upwards 100% the height of the relative coordinate system… `position: absolute;` also frees the element from the document flow. The menu is then free to grow "higher" as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of your `:hover` pseudo-selector:

```
#start_button:hover {
  margin-top: -18px;  /* This causes it to shift up */
}
```

Without that, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qkGR4/3/

Comment: Yes but I want the grey box to be over the black line and without "test" being in it

Comment: @user1951751: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like what I showed but I dont want the grey box to extend beyond the black line if that makes any sense :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `margin-top` attribute from `#start_button:hover`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attribute `margin-top` from `#start_button:hover` and increase the `#start_button:hover > #nav` height:

```
#start_button:hover  {
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background-image:url('images/start.png');
}
#start_button:hover > #nav {
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 131px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qkGR4/5/

Comment: still not what I wanted but changing this fixed it `height: 130px;`

Comment: Ops. I thought that you would like to see the `Test` button in grey when hovered. Fixing the answer